# Simple question -- How to get sma value for close[2], close[3], etc. in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

How can I get the simple moving average value or smoothed moving average value for previous bars in Pine Script?  Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the historical operator on any value in just the same manner we would with close. Eg.

ma = sma(close,50)

ma2 = ma[2]

Or we could do

ma2 = (sma(close,50))[2]

Whatever number we put in there is how many bars back for the value preceding it. FYI there is a limit to how far back you can go with this method.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much.  The tutorials and references are not the best for new coders.

Comment: No worries glad to help! Best of luck